# What's the difference between ember.js extend and create?

Tags: ember.js

What's the difference between `ember.js` Object methods `extend` and `create`?

TLDR: You will find the answer in [Ember guides: classes and instances](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/classes-and-instances/).

Sometimes I see that one in the examples and sometimes the other. In particular, what's the difference between `Em.Application.extend({})` and `Em.Application.create({})`?

If I declare my app like this, what does it mean?

```
Ember.Application.create({
    MyController : Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    }),
});
```

How can I access the instance of MyController? Do I need to create it somehow? I need to push some data into it.

Comment: Well, I have found the difference (creating new "subclass" using extend and creating new "object" when using create). However, if you can describe this better, eventually with notices about some pitfalls developer may find, it could help other beginners (and I'll accept the answer).

Comment: There's nice article [here](http://www.cerebris.com/blog/2012/03/06/understanding-ember-object/)

Comment: Just an update: the Ember docs now have a pretty straightforward explanation of `extend` and `create` under [Classes and Instances](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/classes-and-instances/)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The dead simple answer is that `extend` defines a new JS Class which inherits from the class you're extending, but does not create an instance of that class. `create` creates an instance of the class.

`Em.Application` is a particular case, because you're creating a namespace, not an object instance. I don't know when you'd ever want to `extend` `Em.Application`.

```
App = Em.Application.create(); // I have a new Em.Application namespace
App.A = Em.Object.extend(); // I have defined a new class, App.A, 
                            // which inherits from Em.Object
var a = App.A.create();  // a now contains an instance of App.A.
```

I'd suggest you read "[Naming Conventions](http://www.emberist.com/2012/04/09/naming-conventions.html)", too.

ETA: And "[Understanding Ember Objects](http://www.cerebris.com/blog/2012/03/06/understanding-ember-object/)", as suggested in zaplitny's comment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please, have one more look at my edit and help me understand the way we create ember apps. Thanks.

Comment: I've never seen an application declared like that. What examples are you following that do it that way?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/3059725 or https://github.com/ghempton/ember-router-example

Comment: I see. This is a new pattern I'm not familiar with (declaring `window.App = Em.Application.create`). They're extending Ember.Application at instantiation rather than subclassing (sub-namespacing?) and then instantiating; the patterns I've used before hide the instantiation in the toolchain.

Comment: I'm still confused. How can I access the instance of App.A, for example router or controller, without explicitly creating it in the application constructor?

Comment: You don't generally need to access the instance of your application - you declare controllers, views, statemanagers, etc. within its namespace, and access those instances.

Comment: Look at the examples I have posted above. How does the author declare instance? I can see only "extend" keyword while declaring all controllers and wiews. Are their instances created by the framework then?

Answer (score 0):

From what little I understand, in layman's terms, you **extend** when you want to define a new object idea with properties that will never change(except for reopen), and exist throughout all versions of this object.

You **create** when you want to work with a particular individual (instance of) object. In other words, something with properties that will be changed by actions or other particular instances.

Often you only need to create relationships between objects, you don't need to speak about particular individual objects, but rather the idea of the object. Therefore, you don't need to **create** every time you **extend**.

Hopefully I'm understanding it correctly.