# how to create an ember data transaction

Tags: javascript, ember.js, datastore, ember-data

I'm trying to create a transaction to create a new user.

From the ember-data.js src:

> To create a new transaction, call the `transaction()` method of your
>   application's `DS.Store` instance:
>
> ```
>   var transaction = App.store.transaction();
> ```

I'm trying to create the transaction in a controller

```
App.CreateUserController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    addUser: function() {
        var transaction = App.store.transaction();
    }
});
```

but I'm getting

```
TypeError: App.store is undefined
```

I had this store defined

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: App.Adapter.create({})
});
```

it used a captial S so I tried changing App.store to App.Store and I get

```
TypeError: App.Store.transaction is not a function
```

If I change my App.Store to use a lowercase s I get

```
TypeError: store is undefined
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a store instead of extending it. The convention is to use lowercase letters when you create an instance, so instead of App.Store, you should create a store and name it App.store

```
App.store = DS.Store.create({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: App.Adapter.create({})
});
```

Then you'll be able to create a transaction

```
var transaction = App.store.transaction();
```

Comment: I tried for an hour to get this working hopelessly. At last I found that the current version of emberdata has removed transactions for some reason, so if you're using the current version, none of these answers will work for you.

Answer (score 4):

Transaction in Ember.js is gone: save the individual record. https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

Comment: The essential part of the answer is "Transaction in Ember.js is gone: save the individual record" !

Answer (score 1):

You've defined `App.Store`, which is a ***class***; you are `extend`ing DS.Store, which is an existing class. The code to create a transaction should be called on an ***instance*** of the store (by convention, classes are capitalized and instances lowercase ).

To create an instance of your defined store:

```
App.store = App.Store.create();
myTransaction = App.store.transaction();
```

Note that you `extend` the Store class to get your own Store class, and you call `create` on your own store class to instantiate it.

See [What's the difference between ember.js extend and create?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654593/whats-the-difference-between-ember-js-extend-and-create) for more information on extend vs create.